# How to prevent an injection attack when building a bash command?

Tags: javascript, bash, shell, code-injection

I am building a bash command programmatically and a part of the command comes from a 3rd-party.

How do I make sure that there is no way to inject code through such a command?

Here an example in JavaScript where the command is built:

```
const filename = "syslog"; 
const cmd = `cat /var/log/${filename} | grep error | wc -l`;
```

What if filename will contain something dangerous? For instance:

```
const filename = "syslog' > /dev/null && python -m SimpleHTTPServer #"
```

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing where the filename comes from. People often solve this problem by creating a temp file with a known safe name and then writing the content into it first. https://github.com/sindresorhus/tempy (for JS land, exists in all other languages). You are correct that you should not put user input into a string executed by a shell.

Comment: *I am building a bash command programmatically and a part of the command comes from a 3rd-party.* that's a bad idea, don't do that. Instead, run the command `cat /var/log/"$1" | grep error | wc -l` with `filename` as the first positional parameter if possible.

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks for the idea! Does such a method have any caveats (like "../../" inside the filename)?

Comment: @nlta In my case the filename comes from an alphanumeric ID generated by a 3rd-party software, but who knows, if it can be manipulated.

Comment: @Andrej yes. But that's a trivial case, you can check whether `filename` has a dot-dot component either in JS or the shell with no performance drawback. And if you know `/var/log` doesn't contain any symbolic link to outside, I think you're safe.

Answer (score 2):

In `bash` at least (I am not sure for the others), enclosing a string with single quotes ensures that whatever is in the string is not evaluated:

```sh
$ echo '/dev/${blah}\n><&§è;:'
/dev/${blah}\n><&§è;:
$ ls '/dev/null ; format c:\ :-p'
ls: cannot access '/dev/null ; format c:\ :-p': No such file or directory
```

So, if you ensure there's no single quote in your string beforehand, you should be ok...

Comment: But in any case, I would not trust that either...  
I'd probably check for the existence of the file with a known API first.  
eg. fs.exists() in NodeJS

Comment: Note that this doesn't protect against path traversal attacks (e.g. if the filename starts with `../../`).

Comment: Yes, I was going just to say that ...
I'd check also for '/', then

Comment: I was also thinking about using single quotes but I am not sure what are the limitations. As @GordonDavisson said, there are still some caveats.

Comment: What about combining this with `readlink -f` and check the start matches the path?
eg. `readlink -f '/var/log/../../etc/shadow'` ==> '/etc/shadow'.startsWith('/var/log/')

Comment: This doesn't protect against injection. What happens when ${blah} is ' && rf -rf / && echo '

Comment: The whole point of the comment was that '${blah}' is not evaluated and stays as is.  
```bash
root@fb4619155f29:/# export blah=' && rf -rf / && echo ' 
root@fb4619155f29:/# ls '/dev/${blah}'
ls: cannot access '/dev/${blah}': No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Another more secure idea would be to first get the list of all possible files
eg. `find /var/log/ -type f`
and check the if the input matches any of them ...

Comment: Thanks, but this would be quite expensive. What if there are 100k files? It also would help only if the file exists. What if the file does not exist and should be created? My question was more general, the example was meant more for demo purposes.

Comment: If, in addition, the files are to be created, I would really not trust any input. In that case I think it should be tested against something like a limited charset or a regular expression ...